# How to select LRAW from DB Table?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I have the following code:

```
 SELECT S~CLUSTD AS ZZCLUSTD
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_viqmel_iflos
   FROM viqmel AS v
     LEFT OUTER JOIN stxl AS S
      ON s~tdobject = @lv_qmel
      AND s~tdname = v~qmnum
```

Select statement generates following short dump:

```
Only the prefixed length field can be used to read from the LRAW field or
LCHR field S~CLUSTD.
```

Internal table `lt_viqmel_iflos` is type `viqmel_iflos`(DB view which contains DB table `QMEL`) to which I appended `ZZCLUSTD` type char200.

The problem is that I cannot make ZZCLUSTD type LRAW in QMEL because I get the following error:

[image]

So my only option (that I am aware of) remains to select into char200 the first 200 characters of LRAW.

Is this even possible?

Or is there another way to select LRAW data?

I found the info about the topic, but unfortunately I can't adapt it to my scenario:[read LRAW data](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12151589/you-can-only-read-out-of-the-lraw-or-lchr-field-xx.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there are two questions here.

---

The **first** one is the activation error of table `QMEL`:

> Field `ZZCLUSTD` does not have a preceding length field of type INT4

A DDIC table containing a column of type LCHR and LRAW, **requires** that it's always immediately preceded with a column of type [**INT2 or INT4**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenddic_character_byte_types.htm) (although the message says only INT4).

---

The **second** question is about how to read such a field. **Both columns** must always be read at the same time, and the INT2/INT4 column must be "read before" the LCHR/LRAW column. The only reference I could find to explain this restriction is in the note [302788 - LCHR/LRAW fields in logical cluster tables](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/302788/E).

The INT2 column of `STXL` table being named `CLUSTR`, the following code works:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_viqmel_iflos,
         clustr   TYPE stxl-clustr, "INT2
         zzclustd TYPE stxl-clustd, "LCHR
       END OF ty_viqmel_iflos.
DATA lt_viqmel_iflos TYPE TABLE OF ty_viqmel_iflos.

SELECT S~CLUSTR, S~CLUSTD AS ZZCLUSTD
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_viqmel_iflos
   FROM viqmel AS v
     INNER JOIN stxl AS S
      ON s~tdname = v~qmnum
   UP TO 100 ROWS.
```

---

NB: there is a confusion in your question, where you refer to both `CLUSTD` from `STXL` and `ZZCLUSTD` from `QMEL`. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve exactly.

NB: if you want to read the texts from the table `STXL`, there's another solution by calling the function module `READ_TEXT_TABLE`, or `READ_MULTIPLE_TEXTS` if you prefer. They were made available by the note 2261311. In case you don't have or can't install these function modules, you may try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sandraros/8b54e98166809fdb7ae39b1c11a846fe) which does the same thing. It also contains a reference to another discussion.

NB: for information, to be more precise, LRAW contains bytes, not characters, and for data clusters (case of `STXL`), these bytes correspond to any values (characters in the case of `STXL`) zipped with the statement [`EXPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapexport_data_cluster.htm) and are to be unzipped with [`IMPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapimport_data_cluster.htm)`.

Comment: ZZCLUSTD is not very relevant to the problem. It is just the naming convention I must use in order to append CLUSTD to DB-table QMEL. I managed to select the data using also CLUSTR, as you suggested. I extracted the data from CLUSTD using function module READ_TEXT. Thank you for all the info provided!

Comment: My comment was more about I don't understand the relationship between your two questions: you create ZZCLUSTD/QMEL (error message in ABAP dictionary) but you read CLUSTD/STXL (syntax error in ABAP). It's two distinct questions on a very close topic.

Comment: I thought that the reason I got the syntax error was maybe because ZZCLUSTD/QMEL had that error.